# if window.location == index (homepage)

Tags: if-statement, indexing, window.location, except

I wanna do a jquery action on every site except the homepage (index).
I can not find out how to setup the if-statement with window.location
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do:
`if(window.location.pathname != "{ do something }")
{
  //run home page jquery.
}`

But if prefer **PHP** like
 `<?php if ( !is_home() ) { ?>
    ====  jquery code here =====
<?php } ?>`

Good luck!! :)

Comment: What would "do something" look like if i want to target the index of www.exmaple.com. i testet "www.example.com" and "http://www.example.com/index.php" nothing worked.  i can´t use php because it´s blocked in our cms. my code looks like this `if ( $(window).width() > 1404 && (window.location.pathname != "http://www.example.com/index.php")) {
 do something
 } `

Comment: ..hm..how blocked? which CMS you use? :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for as the pathname will be a single / if you are at the home page in MVC. I am not sure about webforms but would assume the same if not it would be the page name such as /Default.aspx.

```
(function selfRunning() {
if (window.location.pathname.length > 1) {
    alert(window.location.pathname);
}
```

})();

Comment: yeah this might solve the index problem but 1.) how can i check for specific pages or 2.) pages which contain a specific keyword in the url ? an answer to this two questions would be nice :-)

Comment: pathname is a string so you can use contains('value') or just look to see if pathname == '/yourPage'; remember the home page in MVC will always just be '/' for the pathname.